# React Material Ui Dynamically built menu onClose not getting reference to variable inside function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm working on creating an app and decided to dynamically build the settings menu based on some JSON.

```
{
    catagories: [
      {
        name: "General",
        index: 1,
        items: [{
          name: "Dark Mode",
          index: 1,
          type: "bool",
          value: false,
        }],
      },
      {
        name: "Output",
        index: 2,
        items: [{
          name: "Add Quotes",
          index: 1,
          type: "bool",
          value: false,
        },
        {
          name: "Escape Spaces",
          index: 2,
          type: "bool",
          value: false,
        }],
      },
    ]
  }
```

This json is then processed by this script inside a function component. Currently the index and type properties are not used.

```
function SideMenuSettings(props) {
  const { changeSettings } = props; //function that actully changes the settings
  const { settings } = props; // object that contains settings to load the ui with
  let rows = []
  let cat = settings.catagories;
  for(var i = 0; i < cat.length; i++) {
    rows.push(<Typography variant="h5">{cat[i].name}</Typography>);
    for(var j = 0; j < cat[i].items.length; j++) {
      let name = cat[i].items.name;
      
      rows.push(
        <FormControlLabel
          value={name}
          control={<Switch color="primary" />}
          label={name}
          labelPlacement="start"
          onChange={() => {
          changeSettings({
            name: name,
            value: event.target.value,
          });
        }}
      />
    );
    }
  }
  return (
    <FormControl component="fieldset">

    <FormGroup aria-label="position" column>
      {rows}
    </FormGroup>
    </FormControl>
  );
}
```

This mostly works, except I need to have an `onClick` function for the switches generated from it.
When run, `name` is undefined. I tried using a function to return a function that runs the `change setting' function, but it didn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing, because there is no way to test without a code snippet, but I am looking at the code and you are using `event.target.value` but you are not passing `event`, I don't get it. Also shouldn't name be `name: event.target.name`?

Comment: `event` is a property of `window` so I don't need to pass it, and if I log it to the console it returns the correct value. I'll look into using `event.target.name`.